# Could the "private" be changed to "public" on the invitation form?

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]

I noticed that on the main site even now the invitation form says "private beta" instead of "public beta". Could that please be changed?

Comment: *Can reproduce* ;) Yes, this should be changed, alongside with the beta-label being added to the navbar.

Comment: Skimming through some other (public) beta sites, that box probably shouldn't even be there at all. Possibly a result of us getting our own design from private beta stage meaning that this didn't automatically go away when we entered public beta?

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 Yes. It's a result of this site having started out a bit different. So, either the SE team can choose to remove that invitation form altogether or at least make the necessary changes.

Comment: @Blue That's... odd. I don't see it. Would you mind taking a full-page screenshot for me, please?

Comment: @Blue Hah, I was just looking at Home, not Questions. The widget's removed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, something's weird there. The private beta invitation should have been removed by now, I believe. The new site design should have no impact on how that works. I will have someone take a look.

Comment: Why is this no longer under review? Is there any new result?

Comment: @MEE I thought that perhaps marking it [status-review] might be tripping up whatever process the dev-on-bug-duty follows (sorta like putting an issue "on hold" maybe), but turns out I was wrong. I double-checked this morning and this issue is still in whatever queue gets it done sooner than later, so my concerns were unwarranted. This is still a thing.

Comment: ok, I just looked at this in the question list and wondered why it was missing the tag status-review. Thanks for explaining me.

Comment: Hi @Robert is there anything new about the status of this bug report?

Comment: @MEE No, unfortunately bug handling is a bit of black box to me. I inquired and escalated this, but I don't know what the process/plan is beyond that.